# Mathematica: change x^y to power(x,y)

Tags: sql

MySql does not understand the operator "^", i.e., we must use power(x,y) instead of x^y. How to translate x^y to power(x,y)?.

Thanks

César Lozada

Comment: What exactly is the input and output?

Comment: try `CForm[x^y]`

Comment: I'll take a longshot and propose: `ClearAll[x,y,power] x^y /.x_^y_:>power[x,y]//TraditionalForm`

Comment: Is this even for Mathematica (round brackets)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.